# Can't stop node.js app started with pm2 process manager

Tags: node.js, npm, pm2

I want to rebuild my node+vue.js app to update the changes I made. The app was started with [pm2](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/overview/), but the problem is that I can't see anything when I do `pm2 ls`. The list is empty. On the other hand, the node app is running. I tried to kill it with pid, but it is restarting immediately.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider if you issued **pm2** command with other users like **root**?

Comment: @KevinLaw Worked, I can see my app on the pm2 list with root. Thank you! I