# Node app run with PM2 doesn't stop when process is stopped

Tags: node.js, pm2

I've noticed that apps started with PM2 will keep running even after processes have been stopped or deleted. This doesn't always happen, especially if the process has just been started, but if it's been left to run for a while it will always happen.

I start my process with:

```
pm2 start npm --name "next" -- start
```

This  works as intended.

However if I come back to it a couple of days later and run:

```
pm2 stop next
```

The process will be stopped and disappear from the output of `pm2 ls`.
Unfortunately the app itself is still running in the background and the only way I have found to stop it is completely rebooting my server which isn't optimal.

My problem is similar to the one mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52377977/cant-stop-node-js-app-started-with-pm2-process-manager), however the solution didn't work for me.

Output of `ps aux || grep node`:

```
ps aux || grep "node"
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.5 225444  5868 ?        Ss   Sep09   1:42 /lib/systemd/systemd --system --deserialize 38
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep09   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         4  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         6  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [mm_percpu_wq]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep09   0:33 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    Sep09   2:47 [rcu_sched]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    Sep09   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep09   0:00 [migration/0]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep09   0:10 [watchdog/0]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep09   0:00 [cpuhp/0]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep09   0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        14  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [netns]
root        15  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep09   0:00 [rcu_tasks_kthre]
root        16  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep09   0:00 [kauditd]
root        17  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep09   0:01 [khungtaskd]
root        18  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep09   0:00 [oom_reaper]
root        19  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [writeback]
root        20  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep09   0:00 [kcompactd0]
root        21  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Sep09   0:00 [ksmd]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        SN   Sep09   0:00 [khugepaged]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [crypto]
root        24  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [kintegrityd]
root        25  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [kblockd]
root        26  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [ata_sff]
root        27  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [md]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [edac-poller]
root        29  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [devfreq_wq]
root        30  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [watchdogd]
root        34  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep09  21:32 [kswapd0]
root        35  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [kworker/u3:0]
root        36  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep09   0:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
root        78  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [kthrotld]
root        79  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [acpi_thermal_pm]
root        80  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep09   0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root        81  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [scsi_tmf_0]
root        82  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep09   0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root        83  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [scsi_tmf_1]
root        89  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
root        98  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [kstrp]
root       115  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [charger_manager]
root       153  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep09   0:00 [scsi_eh_2]
root       154  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [scsi_tmf_2]
root       155  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:58 [kworker/0:1H]
root       266  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [raid5wq]
root       318  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Sep09   0:54 [jbd2/vda1-8]
root       319  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root       404  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [iscsi_eh]
root       408  0.0  0.0 105904   228 ?        Ss   Sep09   0:00 /sbin/lvmetad -f
root       413  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [ib-comp-wq]
root       414  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [ib_mcast]
root       415  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [ib_nl_sa_wq]
root       417  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep09   0:00 [rdma_cm]
root       698  0.0  0.9 501844  9800 ?        Ss   Sep18   1:46 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root       842  0.0  0.1 652392  1420 ?        Ssl  Sep09   0:18 /usr/bin/lxcfs /var/lib/lxcfs/
root       843  0.0  0.4  71488  4416 ?        Ss   Sep09   0:05 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
root       848  0.0  0.7 187700  7924 ?        Ssl  Sep09   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal
root       854  0.0  0.1 287992  1416 ?        Ssl  Sep09   2:48 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
root       856  0.0  0.1  31748  1240 ?        Ss   Sep09   0:07 /usr/sbin/cron -f
syslog     861  0.0  0.1 263036  1776 ?        Ssl  Sep09   1:51 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
root       864  0.0  0.7 170876  7808 ?        Ssl  Sep09   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
message+   865  0.0  0.3  50280  3092 ?        Ss   Sep09   2:10 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation --syslog-only
daemon     891  0.0  0.0  28332   212 ?        Ss   Sep09   0:00 /usr/sbin/atd -f
root       895  0.0  0.2  72296  2068 ?        Ss   Sep09   2:17 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root       903  0.0  0.0  16412   140 ttyS0    Ss+  Sep09   0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 ttyS0 vt220
root       907  0.0  0.1 288880  1524 ?        Ssl  Sep09   1:11 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
root       908  0.0  0.0  14888   136 tty1     Ss+  Sep09   0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear tty1 linux
mysql      943  0.1 20.6 1161772 208636 ?      Sl   Sep09  68:26 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
leonardo  1068  0.0  0.1  76636  1028 ?        Ss   Sep09   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
leonardo  1072  0.0  0.2 111788  2388 ?        S    Sep09   0:00 (sd-pam)
root      6750  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    Oct12   0:01 [kworker/0:1]
root     13084  0.0  0.0  42904   820 ?        Ss   Sep12   0:30 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
leonardo 16084  0.0  0.0   4632    72 ?        S    11:26   0:00 sh -c NODE_PATH=. NODE_ENV=production node server.js
leonardo 16085  0.0  9.0 1303708 90912 ?       Sl   11:26   0:05 node server.js
www-data 16095  0.0  6.5 592644 65988 ?        S    11:26   0:02 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 16096  0.0  6.1 512560 62084 ?        S    11:26   0:01 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     16993  0.0  0.0 105692   996 ?        Ss   12:39   0:00 sshd: leonardo [priv]
leonardo 17093  0.0  0.0 107992  1008 ?        S    12:39   0:00 sshd: leonardo@pts/1
leonardo 17094  0.0  0.1  23204  1716 pts/1    Ss+  12:39   0:00 -bash
systemd+ 17556  0.0  0.0  71848   724 ?        Ss   Sep12   0:03 /lib/systemd/systemd-networkd
systemd+ 17571  0.0  0.1  70756  1872 ?        Ss   Sep12   1:13 /lib/systemd/systemd-resolved
systemd+ 17585  0.0  0.0 141928   596 ?        Ssl  Sep12   0:04 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd
root     17604  0.0  4.3 184004 43936 ?        S<s  Sep12   7:58 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root     18184  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    14:11   0:00 [kworker/0:0]
leonardo 18215  0.0  4.4 966088 44652 ?        Ssl  14:12   0:01 PM2 v3.5.1: God Daemon (/home/leonardo/.pm2)
www-data 18227  0.0  5.7 590632 58468 ?        S    14:12   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18231  0.0  4.6 511832 46832 ?        S    14:12   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18232  0.0  2.0 504524 20264 ?        S    14:12   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     18261  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    14:14   0:00 [kworker/u2:1]
root     18311  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    14:19   0:00 [kworker/u2:0]
www-data 18368  0.0  3.6 505148 37244 ?        S    14:26   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     18438  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I    14:35   0:00 [kworker/u2:2]
www-data 18441  0.0  1.9 504244 19308 ?        S    14:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18442  0.0  1.9 504244 19308 ?        S    14:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18443  0.0  1.9 504244 19308 ?        S    14:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18445  0.0  1.9 504304 19440 ?        S    14:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     18458  0.0  0.7 105684  7216 ?        Ss   14:36   0:00 sshd: leonardo [priv]
leonardo 18538  0.0  0.5 107984  5504 ?        S    14:36   0:00 sshd: leonardo@pts/0
leonardo 18539  0.1  0.5  23204  5144 pts/0    Ss   14:36   0:00 -bash
leonardo 18558  0.0  0.3  40092  3460 pts/0    R+   14:37   0:00 ps aux
root     24135  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep12   0:00 [xfsalloc]
root     24136  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   Sep12   0:00 [xfs_mru_cache]
do-agent 28788  0.0  1.3 496372 14064 ?        Ssl  Sep14   5:51 /opt/digitalocean/bin/do-agent --syslog
```

My `server.js`:

```
const express = require( 'express' )
const axios = require( 'axios' )
const next    = require( 'next' )
const cacheableResponse = require('cacheable-response')

// Import middleware.
const routes = require( './routes' )

// Setup app.
const app     = next( { dev: 'production' !== process.env.NODE_ENV } )
const handle  = app.getRequestHandler()
const handler = routes.getRequestHandler( app )

const ssrCache = cacheableResponse({
  ttl: 1000 * 60 * 60, // 1hour
  get: async ({ req, res, pagePath, queryParams }) => ({
    data: await app.renderToHTML(req, res, pagePath, queryParams)
  }),
  send: ({ data, res }) => res.send(data)
})

app.prepare()
  .then( () => {

    // Create server.
    const server = express();

    // Use our handler for requests.
    server.use( handler );

    // Don't remove. Important for the server to work. Default route.
    server.get( '*', ( req, res ) => {
      ssrCache({ req, res })
    } );

    // Get current port.
    const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

    // Error check.
    server.listen( port, err => {
      if ( err ) {
        throw err;
      }

      // Where we starting, yo!
      console.log( `> Ready on port ${port}...` );
    } );
  } );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen due to multiple reason. Please check if the app itself is running any demon from within. What do you see when you run `ps aux || grep node`. If you can post your `app.js` or `server.js` or `index.js` or anything which acts as main file of your application file here that would help to diagnose the issue.

if you are setting any environment variable like production you can do it explicitly i.e `export NODE_ENV=production`

You can start the server.js app without npm with pm2 with below command
`pm2 start server.js -- --prod` This should work without any problem.

For anything more than this i would recommend the [pm2 config file](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/) this is the right way of using pm2 scripts.

Comment: Added both to the OP. Not sure what I'm looking for in `ps aux`, there doesn't seem to be anything directly related to node but I could be wrong.

Comment: `leonardo 16085  0.0  9.0 1303708 90912 ?       Sl   11:26   0:05 node server.js` this is your node process. can you do pm2 stop next and see if it still is present in ps aux.

Comment: Yeah it's still there even after stopping. Any way to automatically stop this when I stop pm2?

Comment: That started it but in development mode. My current start command is `NODE_PATH=. NODE_ENV=production node server.js`, how do I use that with pm2?

Comment: Could you elaborate on where to use `export NODE_ENG=production`? Running `pm2 start server.js -- --prod` started it in development mode. Currently looking into the config files, thank you for the help.

Comment: Run the command `export NODE_ENV=production` just before the `pm2 start server.js -- --prod` or `pm2 start server.js -- --production` based on what your app file is looking for to identify the environment.

Comment: That's worked! I will look more into the pm2 config since that seems a lot easier to use! Thank you for your help!